# Save in global var result of "file.txt" reading (Ajax + JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've looked everywhere but i can't find anything that works. 
How can i save in a **global** var the result ?

```
var myvar='';
var array;
$.ajax({
    async: false, //Edit
    type:'post',
    url: 'text.txt',
    dataType:'text',
    success: function(data) {
    useReturnData(data);
    }
});

function useReturnData(data){
    myvar = data;
    array = myvar.split('\n');
    document.write(array[0]);           // <- here it prints array[0]
};

function printVar() {
    document.write(array[0]);           // <- here it doesn't do anything
};

printVar();
```

Comment: I just call it after the declaration, see "Edit:"..

Comment: There is no guarantee that `array` contains the proper data. You need to do printing stuff via the callback to `$.ajax`. As usual, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) should help.

Comment: you have to add  async: false to ajax options

Comment: thanks for answering, i've seen the post but i still don't get how to save my  data in a global var.
Since i need to work on the data, now just print it..

Comment: @Suhail Keyjani, this still doesn't work..

Comment: @ Aldi Piroli, i test it and it work, please try to alert not document.write